# Synchronisation failed: peer is unknown or unhealthy

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, p2pool

I am getting this error message while synching my geth node: `eth/downloader/downloader.go:278] Synchronisation failed: peer is unknown or unhealthy`

1. Why would a peer be considered 'unhealthy'?
2. Is there a log file I can check for more information about this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're hitting an [errUnknownPeer](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=org%3Aethereum%20errUnknownPeer&type=Code&ref=searchresults) error.

From the code in [downloader.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/0f036f62092e306f5971478780b7bcf88ea5a887/eth/downloader/downloader.go):

```
// Retrieve the origin peer and initiate the downloading process
p := d.peers.Peer(id)
if p == nil {
    return errUnknownPeer
}
```

Here we're trying to use a previously known peer with an id of `id`, but which no longer appears in the list of known peers. (So our look-up in the current list of peers returns `nil`.)

There's nothing in the code to explicity define "unhealthy" with regards to peers - it only appears in the error string - but from the context it means either:

- the peer is no longer online, or
- the peer is online but unable to communicate.

Both of which means the peer can no longer be discovered.

I can't see anything in the code that would log anything more useful, but you could try setting a higher verbosity level in the console if it happens repeatedly. (Using `debug.verbosity(x)`, where `x` is the logging level.)

Comment: My node is not syncing because of this, seeing many such peers. How to fix?